# Throw custom null assertion with !! operator in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I would like to translate the following code from **android** java to kotlin

```
 public static void Initialize(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new AzureServiceAdapter(context);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("AzureServiceAdapter is already initialized");
        }
    }
```

I have read up the difference between `?` and `!!` operators but could not get the expression I wanted. Basically I would like to throw a custom exception when the variable is not null. However, I could not get it to throw a custom exception when using `!!` as it only throws NPE.

```
 public fun Initialize(context: Context){
        mInstance!!.AzureServicesAdapter(context) ?: throw IllegalStateException("AzureServiceAdapter is already initialised")
    }
```

Above is my self converted code to kotlin but I am not sure if this is the right move. Thanks for the help.

Comment: in such cases leaving the code as is is the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same thing in Kotlin.

```kotlin
 fun Initialize(context: Context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = AzureServiceAdapter(context)
        } else {
            throw IllegalStateException("AzureServiceAdapter is already initialized")
        }
    }
```

Keep your code simple and understandable for everyone.

Comment: Hi, does that mean that I am not able to use any null safety operator in the code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
mInstance?.AzureServicesAdapter(context) ?: throw IllegalStateException("AzureServiceAdapter is already initialised")
```